# How to create Custom REST API in SuiteCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Im new to SuiteCRM.

Can any one tell how to create a REST API from scratch for a custom module.

I went through the developer guide, but i need to know like in which file those REST API call has to be made (Referring the PHP example from the below link)

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/REST/PHP/Creating_Documents/#Overview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your own API to your module, you probably are looking for https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Extending_Web_Services/

---

The example code you posted calls the `REST API` from the "outside" and works independently of Sugar.

So you can just save the example anywhere as `test.php` and run it with `php -f /path/to/test.php`.

You could also save it e.g. in the Sugar root dir to make it accessible to the web and just call it from your browser's address bar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jay, i followed the doc and im facing PHP fatal error which says:  PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'service/v4_1/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php' (include_path='D:\\Ampps\\php-7.1\\pear') and i have posted the question in a seperate post also.. Could you suggest on the same/.

Comment: Here is the link for the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788138/php-require-once-failed-opening-required-include-path

Comment: Documentation for SuiteCRM: https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/api-4_1/#_adding_custom_api_methods