# PHP require_once(): Failed opening required include_path

Tags: php, pear

Im using Php 7.1 in windows.

**Error i get:**

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Suite_dev/service/v4_1/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php' (include_path='D:/Ampps/php-7.1/pear') in D:\Ampps\www\Suite_dev\custom\service\v4_1_custom\SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom.php on line 4

**Workaround** i did in php ini file:

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = "{$path}\php-7.1\pear"
```

Downloaded and installed php pear and tested pear is working.

Even after pear is installed, i still get above error.

Also tried something like:

```
include('../../../service/v4_1/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php');
```

Still i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

includes in Sugar are usually relative paths based on Sugar's main folder.

So should be
`service/v4_1/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php` *without* a leading `Suite_dev/`

Comment: My actual path was same as u have given...Since it dint work, i tried like the way i have shown!!  in both cases, i get the above err

Comment: PS: for Sugar development (and also production) I strongly recommended using Linux rather than Windows.

Comment: @stack200s Then maybe SuiteCRM changed their directory layout or something. What  version of SuiteCRM are you using? Does the file you are trying to include actually exist?

Comment: im using 7.8.8 and in linux it causes more issues, as posted in their community